# Can any user be invited to chat?

Tags: support, chat, chat-search

Can all users be invited to chat? (Assuming they have sufficient reputation to talk in chat, that is [at least 20 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).) Does every user have a chat profile?

I have tried to search a bit here on meta and the information seems to be contradictory (emphasis mine);

- In [CW answer to How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537#57538) I read that: "*Some* users are active in chat, and you might be able to set up a "private" chat room for you and the user you'd like to contact by visiting their user profile on chat."
- In [Shadow Wizard's answer to What makes someone a chat user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277119#277121) I read that: "If you want to invite someone to chat, the *only single requirement* is for that other user to have 20 reputation points."

---

I have even tried to test this myself. I searched for users which have at least 20 reputation points, but the accounts are relatively new. (So that the probability that they some their comments have been moved to chat is lower.) For example, [this user on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/457386/felix-klein). But when I tried to search for this user in chat, I did not find their user profile.

[image: Felix Klein - chat screenshot]

An to add another example, for [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/361619/user107952) I was unable to find their profile page on chat linked to meta.SE, but I still found that user on [Stack Exchange chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/101019/user107952).

[image: user107952 - chat screenshot]

Comment: Yeah, looks like I was wrong and only users who ever visited chat have chat profile (i.e. the chat profile is only created when a user visits chat). Will try to test using fresh sock, but it will take time, hopefully you'll get official answer before that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the reply. The reason I have asked this was partly that you mentioned inviting *any* user also in a [relatively recent discussion](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298690/enabling-high-rep-users-other-than-those-who-post-a-question-to-ping-the-closers).

Comment: Well, that discussion was about high rep users who voted to close a question... I believe only few of those never even visited chat so it's less relevant.